# React Native Expo-av has a slight delay between button touch and sound play even after preloading sound

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-av

### Update:

I'm leaving this to save research and time for others.
I used onPressIn instead of onPress for better results.
The events are called as follows.
onPressIn --> onPressOut --> onPress

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPressIn={() => {sound.play()}}>

        <View><Text></Text></View>
        
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

---

As the title says, i'm trying to use expo-av for an instrument app where sound should be instantly played on press. I tried preloading the sound and the delay shortened but there was a still about 50ms of lag.

App.js

```js
import { playSound } from "PlaySound";

export default function App() {
  const [sound, setSound] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    const getStateData = async () => {
      setSound(await playSound(require(`./assets/Sound/ding.mp3`)));
    };

    getStateData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback
      onPress={() => {
        sound.play();
      }}
    >
      <View>
        <Text></Text>
      </View>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
  );
}
```

PlaySound.js

```js
import { Audio } from "expo-av";

export async function playSound(path) {
  const audio = await Audio.Sound.createAsync(path);

  return {
    async play() {
      await audio.sound.replayAsync();
    },
  };
}
```

Any help to reduce the lag would be appreciated

What's expected is for the sound to be instantaneous and not have any lag.